# При повороте экрана открывается последнее открытое диалоговое окно

Tags: android

Залогировала все места, где открывается хоть какой-то диалог - ничего.
Проект большой очень, не могу привести. Конечно, без кода трудно что-то сказать, но может у кого-то есть идеи?
Может диалог открываться как-то кроме showDialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это известная проблема. Решается перегрузкой метода `оnPrepareDialog()` - вызывается всякий раз перед тем как откроется диалог. По умолчанию `super.onPrepareDialog()` просто сохраняет ранее введенные параметры. Вам надо это "перебить" в своем коде.

Сейчас этот метод, начиная с API 13 объявлен устаревшим `@deprecated`, но все равно работает. Но раз вы используете `showDialog()`, который тоже `@deprecated` - значит вам в самую жилу :)

Answer (score 1):

**DialogFragment** сохроняет свое состояние в стеке, и при повороте этот **стек полностью востанавливается**. не могу утверждать но возможно у вас диалог просто прячется методом **hide()** , а вот **dismiss()** для него не вызывается.

очень часто так делают ребята которые не желают заморачиваться **с падениями связаными с вызовом dismiss()**.

Answer (score 1):

Переопределите метод `onConfigurationChanged`
не забудьте в манифесте добавить что-то вроде  `android:configChanges="orientation"` в `<activity> </activity>`

т.е. вы сделаете так, чтобы при смене ориентации экрана вообще ничего не происходило
должно помочь

Answer (score -1):

При повороте экрана и смене ориентации вызывается `onResume()` текущей активити. Возможно внутри этого метода востанавливается состояние с показанным диалогом.

Comment: А что значит "восстанавливается состояние"? showDialog не вызывается